# disappearing hermit crab?

Tags: aquarium

I was spraying and feeding my crabs last night when I realized there was one missing. I only have 3 hermit crabs now so every-time I go over to them I check and just make sure I can see them or where they have dug to hide. I went to spray them around 8am yesterday, saw them all there huddled together, then I come home around 2pm and checked up on them again and I see my smallest one has moved away like he was going for food and water. I come home at 6 and now there’s only 2. now you may be thinking well maybe he’s out of the shell and hiding/molting or maybe another crab has eaten him or something of the sort. but no crab…. and no shell…. It would be more understandable if I found at least the shell but nothing. I have moved everything around and cannot find this crab. I will also mention they have a top to their cage that’s the black metal with holes all over the top, but there’s no way the crab could have gotten up there let alone let himself out with the top on. I’m genuinely so confused, and ideas or tips are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I read that when they are molting they will bury themselves for a bit. Some say as they get bigger they can stay buried for a very long time. I sure hope you find it. I even seen people say they are very good escape artists and if given a way to can and will escape. Best of luck to you!! I have always wanteda hurmet crab but know what they smell like when one dies and no thank you!!! (Teacher had one when I was in highschool that died one weekend and by class Monday the whole school stunk)

Comment: Would you please give some source where your knowledge comes from? You read -> website, book's title...

Comment: @Allerleirauh They did give a bit of personal experience as well; admittedly not very well spoken grammatically but it's still there. As for the citation, yes, that should definitely be in there.